# Exact Meaning of "Slop" in Lucene SpanNearQuery (or slop in ElasticSearch span_near)

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, proximity

***Question 1:*** In Lucene's `SpanNearQuery` (or `span_near` in ElasticSearch), what is the exact meaning of `slop`? Is it the number of words separating the two matching words, or is it the separating number of words plus 1?

For example, suppose your indexed text is: `foo bar biz`

Which queries would match this text: `"foo biz"~0`, `"foo biz"~1`, `"foo biz"~2`

I would expect that the first wouldn't match and the last would. But what about the middle?

***Question 2:*** Now a second and more complex corollary question: how is `slop` handled if there are more than two search clauses? Is it applied to *each* pair of clauses or *any* pair of clauses.

For example, suppose you construct a `SpanNearQuery` with three clauses: `foo`, `bar`, `biz`.  What slop is needed to match the same indexed text above?  I would expect a slop of `2` definitely would, but what about `0` or `1`?

Similarly, with the same three clause query, what slop is needed to match the text: `foo bar ble biz`

Comment: You have a question where you can get the exact answer by trying it out.

Comment: Ya, I kind of figured that... but sometimes writing it down on SO crystallizes the problem in your head.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

***Question 1:*** Slop is the number of words separating the span clauses. So slop 0 would mean they are adjacent.  In the example I gave, slop of 1 would match.

***Question 2:*** When there are more than two span near clauses, each clause must be connected to at least one other clause by no more than slop words separating them AND all of the clauses must be connected to each other through a chain.  However, each clause need not be separated by slop words to every other clause.

For the first example in question 2: slop of 0, 1, and 2 would all match. Slop of zero matches even though `foo` and `biz` are separated by more than one because there is a chain through all clauses.

For the second example in question 2: slop of 0 would not match because `biz` is separated from all other clauses by more than 0 slop.  Slop of 1 would match because `foo` and `bar` are separated by 0 slop, in addition `bar` and `biz` are separated by 1 slop.  It matches even though `foo` and `biz` are separated by more than one because there is a chain through all clauses. Slop of 2 would obviously match.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I'm using `match_phrase` with `slop=0` and it works as you describe. Let's assume I need to boost score for adjacent terms  (`slop=0`) only, so that terms with more unmatched positions will be less relevant like `foo biz` (higher score) while `foo biz dev` lower score, how to achieve that?

Comment: @loretoparisi I guess, you simply need to boost the part of your query with lower slop by wrapping it into a BoostQuery.

Answer (score 0):

it's explained in Span near query

Matches spans which are near one another. One can specify slop, the maximum number of intervening unmatched positions,
as well as whether matches are required to be in-order. The span near query maps to Lucene SpanNearQuery.

Official document -https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-near-query.html

Example
You want to match Mr. Bush and get  details about  them . Since there are two
words which are not similar ,slop value is 2

Mr. Jeorge Willam Bush,
Mr  Sean Willam Bush,
Mr  James Kane Bush

Sample DSL request-

```
  GET school/_search
    {
     "query":{
       "match_phrase": {
         "EmpName":
         {
           "query": "Mr. Bush",
           "slop":2
         }
        
       }
     }
    }
```