# Multi-term phrases in Lucene

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, lucene, information-retrieval

I am reading the Lucene in Action book and I do not understand the multi-term phrases part.

The following text is indexed:

> the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

And then you add the following terms to the `PhraseQuery`: ***quick jumped lazy*** with a slop equal 4. That results in a match, but I don't understand how that happens. How do you calculate the number of moves when there are multiple terms? I don't understand how they do it.

The same with the terms ***lazy jumped quick*** with slop equal 8.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781267/exact-meaning-of-slop-in-lucene-spannearquery-or-slop-in-elasticsearch-span-n

Answer (score 2):

The slop is actually an [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).  Inserting extra terms in between them adds 1 to the distance, transposing terms adds 2 (the first edit moving the two terms atop one another).

You can go through the edits one at a time to illustrate:

- `quick jumped lazy` **distance:0**
- `quick _ jumped lazy` **distance:1**
- `quick _ _ jumped lazy` **distance:2**
- `quick _ _ jumped _ lazy` **distance:3**
- `quick _ _ jumped _ _ lazy` **distance:4**

And for the second case:

- `lazy jumped quick` **distance:0**
- `lazy/jumped quick` **distance:1**
- `lazy/jumped/quick` **distance:2** (all three terms superimposed, in the same position)
- `quick lazy/jumped` **distance:3**
- `quick jumped lazy` **distance:4**
- `quick _ jumped lazy` **distance:5**
- `quick _ _ jumped lazy` **distance:6**
- `quick _ _ jumped _ lazy` **distance:7**
- `quick _ _ jumped _ _ lazy` **distance:8**